# c:forEach not executed on Tomcat 7, but working good with Tomcat 8

Tags: jsp, jstl, tomcat7, tomcat8

I read a lot of blogs about `c:forEach` on Tomcat 7. But could not find my answer.

I have a JSP which uses

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8" import="sk.beans.*"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

and

```
<c:forEach var="menu" items="${Header.getMenu()}">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <c:if test="${empty menu.value}">
   <li><a href="#">${menu.key}</a></li>
  </c:if>
    <c:if test="${not empty menu.value}">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">${menu.key} <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <c:forEach var="subMenu" items="${menu.value}">
        <li><a href="#">${subMenu}</a></li>
        </c:forEach>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </c:if>
  </ul>
  </c:forEach>
```

web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
```

pom.xml uses

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now the problem is - on my JSP everything that is hard-coded is getting printed but the logic inside `c:forEach` is not being executed at all.

Note - the same code block works fine in Tomcat 8. But due to some reasons now I will have to work on Tomcat 7.0.62 and Java 8 is used with this server.

Comment: And what does its print on the stack trace, Have you checked whether are multiple version of same jars in your classpath ?